# How do I send the needed parameters to REFDOCRANGE using NSAPConnector?

Tags: c#, sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to use the `BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETLIST` API from SAP to get some invoices. After looking at the [documentation](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/bapi_billingdoc_getlist.html), I only saw one parameter. But after consulting with the SAP guys, that parameter is like a collection of parameters.

So using SAP .NET Connector, this is how I would normally call an SAP BAPI:

```
using (var connection = new SapConnection("SAP"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SapCommand("BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETLIST", connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("REFDOCRANGE", salesOrderNumber);

    resultDataSet = command.ExecuteDataSet();
}
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work. The actual BAPI is expecting parameters for some fields called `S`, `OP`, `REF_DOC_LO`, and `REF_DOC_HI`. As you can see here:

[image]

But I get errors if I actually use those parameters, basically telling me that they don't exist. So do I just send the data in the `REFDOCRANGE` parameter? Does anyone know how that should be formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `REFDOCRANGE` is not a simple value parameter, it is a structure of type `BAPI_REF_DOC_RANGE`. That structure has several fields, `SIGN`, `OPTION`, `REF_DOC_LOW` and `REF_DOC_HIGH`. You can set those fields by first retrieving a reference to the structure, then setting the individual field values.

It looks like the NSAPConnector doesn't really support complex parameters. I looked at the sources and you only get a basic SapParameter class that has a name and a value.

In native SAP .Net Connector 3 this would look like this (somewhat pseudocode, untested):

```
IRfcFunction fnc = destination.Repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETLIST");
IRfcStructure param = fnc.GetStructure("REFDOCRANGE");
param.SetValue("SIGN", "BT");
param.SetValue("REF_DOC_LOW", salesOrderNumberLow);
param.SetValue("REF_DOC_HIGH", salesOrderNumberHigh);

fnc.Invoke(destination);

IRfcTable tabDetail = fnc.GetTable("BILLINGDOCUMENTDETAIL");
foreach(var row in tabDetail)
{
....   
}
```

If I didn't miss anything and the NSAPConnector-library is indeed missing support for complex parameters, I'd suggest switching to the standard SAP .Net Connector 3. You can get it directly from [SAP](http://service.sap.com/connectors) (SAP Marketplace account needed)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out.